# Запятая перед словом "как" (2)

Tags: пунктуация, как

Нужна ли запятая на месте (,)?

"Она говорит, что я должна забыть то лето. Ах, если бы я знала(,) как..."

Answer (score 4):

Нет, запятая не нужна перед КАК. Если придаточное предложение состоит из одного союзного слова, то запятая перед ним не ставится.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!